# Pointer in constexpr structure to singleton GetInstance() function, how to?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, g++

I would like to have a singleton class and a structure which at the compilation time(constexpr) points to the singleton GetInstance function. (Later i will give this structure to another object in constructor). How to do it properly, because my code is not linking at the moment?

```
#include <cstdio>

class testClass {
    public:
    testClass() {
    }
    virtual ~testClass() {
    }
    static testClass& getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    private:
    static testClass instance;
    int variable;
};

typedef struct {
    int i ;
    testClass& (*ptr)(void);
} struktura;

constexpr struktura s1 = {
    i : 0,
    ptr : &(testClass::getInstance),
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the way to do it properly is to not have a singleton at all

Comment: compiles on my clang if you instantiate the static `instance`